# How do I disable the global application menu in Adobe Reader 9?

Tags: 11.10, appmenu, adobe-reader

how to disable global menu in Adobe reader? the menu link not shown in global menu.
[image]

Answer (score 8):

I found a great way to do this.  All of the answers I was able to find involved launching Adobe Reader in a special way.  Unfortunately I needed it to be part of the launcher.  If you open up:

```
gksudo gedit /opt/Adobe/Reader9/bin/acroread
```

You'll be in the actual Adobe Reader launcher.  Just add the line `export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=` to the first blank space you see (under the commented area that starts with #) and save the file.

Now everytime you launch Adobe Reader it will launch with the UBUNTU_MENUPROXY thing enabled!

Comment: thanks a lot! it works perfectly. I had once tried another method, which changed the setting for all the apps.

Answer (score 5):

This fixed the problem for me (see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11563464):

Create a file (e.g. `98menuproxy` ) in /etc/X11/Xsession.d folder with the line:

```
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=
```

Next login to the GUI, acroreader menus should be visible on the program window itself.