# acroread's drop down menus are blank? How can I fix this?

Tags: adobe

I have Adobe Acrobat Reader version 9.4.2.  All my drop down menus are blank.  How can I fix this?  I can select menu items and stuff happens, but I have no idea what they are because there are no words or letters.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 (Unity).  I've tried both Ambiance and Radiance themes but that didn't help at all.

Comment: See if there is any help here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/73272/how-do-i-disable-the-global-application-menu-in-adobe-reader-9

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)