# adobe reader 9.5.1 - No text in tab / menus

Tags: adobe-reader

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Download I used was version 9.5.1 and this was the version:

> AdbeRdr9.5.1-1_i386linux_enu.deb

It was downladed from the adobe website and installed it using software centre.

When I hit the tab, there is no text showed. The same in the menus but no text.

[image]

Comment: Launch Adobe Reader from a terminal window, and post any output that comes out.  It may signal that it's missing a library.

Comment: @gh403 There is no output on commandline except - `Try dirname --help for more information.`

Answer (score 3):

This might be the duplicate of [How do I disable the global application menu in Adobe Reader 9?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73272/how-do-i-disable-the-global-application-menu-in-adobe-reader-9).

Follow the step by theFisher86, and you will be fine.

Adobe Reader 9.5.1 from Canonical Repository doesn't have this issue. If you want to install Adobe Reader on a friend's PC, enable partner repository and install it via

> sudo apt-get install acroread

Comment: @mp-ngapyin I tried installing from Canonical repository and it doesn't have this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

from what I am seeing it seems to be a QT application.

You can set an environment variable to disable the native menu — that could potentially fix your issues:

```
QT_X11_NO_NATIVE_MENUBAR=1 acroread
```

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationMenu#Kubuntu_Desktop_Installation

Then you can run it from terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and see if it has any effect.

#### How to set the environment variable?

Here is a lengthy description: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

**Edit**: More info how to disable global menu: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/disable-appmenu-global-menu-in-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

Is your set up 32 bit? If no, I suspect this could be the root cause as that is a 32 bit download you used.

Could you please check to see if there is a conflict? If not installing

> ia32-libs

might help. This is a library that allows the smooth running of 32 bit programs on 64 bit installations.

From looking on the launchpad [information](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/acroread) it seems to be a bit behind things for supporting 64 bit. That said, I have had a working acroread on my 64 bit set up so there will be a way. Can you run through the steps you made for the install in a little more detail?

Also I cannot be sure this will work but in your situation I would try uninstalling and reinstalling via apt as a first thing. This can be done like so

> sudo apt-get purge acroread
>
> sudo apt-get install acroread

I use [okular](http://okular.kde.org/) instead of acrobat reader -I find it much better. I would recommend using if you have problems that you can't resolve satisfactorily. I believe you can get it from the software centre.

Comment: Okular doesn't support text highlighting and commenting the way Adobe Reader does. Besides, my question isn't about what's the best PDF reader, but what's the way to properly configure Adobe Reader.

Comment: how have you installed it (i.e. what method did you use)? It would be helpful if you can give some background to the issue.

Comment: Downloaded `AdbeRdr9.5.1-1_i386linux_enu.deb` from the adobe website and installed it using software centre.